# Need help to improve MYSQL SubQuery Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I just learning MYSQL, I have MySql subquery like this:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT brand_name, stars, hh_stock, hh_stock_value, sales_monthly_1, sales_monthly_2, sales_monthly_3, sold_monthly_1, sold_monthly_2,
  sold_monthly_3, price_uvp, price_ecp, price_default, price_margin AS margin, vc_percent as vc, cogs, products_length, products_id, material_expenses,
  MAX(price) AS products_price, SUM(total_sales) AS total_sales,
  IFNULL(MAX(active_age), DATEDIFF(NOW(), products_date_added)) AS products_age, DATEDIFF(NOW(), products_date_added) AS jng_products_age,
  AVG(sales_weekly) AS sales_weekly, AVG(sales_monthly) AS sales_monthly, SUM(total_sold) AS total_sold, SUM(total_returned) AS total_returned,
  ((SUM(total_returned)/SUM(total_sold)) * 100) AS returned_rate
FROM
  (
    SELECT p.products_id, jc.price, jc.price_end_customer AS price_ecp, jc.total_sales, jc.active_age, jc.sales_weekly,
      jc.sales_monthly, jc.total_sold, jc.total_returned, jc.price_uvp, p.price_margin, p.vc_percent, p.material_expenses,
      p.products_date_added, p.stars , pb.brand_name, p.family_id, p.products_price_default AS price_default, pl.sales_monthly_1,
      pl.sales_monthly_2, pl.sales_monthly_3, pl.sold_monthly_1, pl.sold_monthly_2, pl.sold_monthly_3, pst.stock AS hh_stock,
      (pst.stock * p.average_stock_value) AS hh_stock_value, pnc.products_length,
      IF(ploc.cogs IS NULL OR ploc.cogs=0,
         (CASE p.complexity
          WHEN 'F' THEN ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+1.7+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+1.7+0.25+2.2),2)
          WHEN 'E' THEN ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+1.7+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+1.7+0.25+2.2),2)
          WHEN 'N' THEN ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+2.4+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+2.4+0.25+2.2),2)
          WHEN 'M' THEN ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+2.4+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+2.4+0.25+2.2),2)
          WHEN 'I' THEN ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+3.5+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+3.5+0.25+2.2),2)
          WHEN 'H' THEN ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+3.5+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+3.5+0.25+2.2),2)
          ELSE ROUND(5*(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+5+0.25+2.2)/100+(p.material_expenses+(7.5/100*p.material_expenses)+5+0.25+2.2),2) END), ploc.cogs) AS cogs
    FROM products p
      LEFT  JOIN jng_sp_catalog jc ON  jc.products_id=p.products_id
      LEFT JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id = p.products_id AND pd.language_id = 2
      LEFT JOIN products_description2 pd2 ON pd2.products_id = p.products_id
      LEFT JOIN products_brand pb ON pb.products_brand_id = p.products_brand_id
      LEFT JOIN products_log pl ON pl.products_id = p.products_id
      LEFT JOIN products_log_static pls ON pls.products_id=p.products_id
      LEFT JOIN products_local ploc ON ploc.products_id = p.products_id
      LEFT JOIN products_non_configurator pnc ON pnc.products_id = p.products_id
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT shp.products_id, CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(shp.styles_id), ',') AS styles_id
        FROM styles_has_products shp GROUP BY shp.products_id HAVING styles_id NOT LIKE '%,1967,%') subquery_styles ON subquery_styles.products_id = p.products_id
      LEFT JOIN products_stock_temp pst ON pst.products_id=p.products_id WHERE p.active_status='1'  AND p.categories_top_id  =  '1') dt  GROUP BY products_id ORDER BY  products_id;
```

The result of explain is like this:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys       | key         | key_len | ref                                | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | p          | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY             | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                               |  40458 |     1.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pb         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_brand_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ploc       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pl         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pls        | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pst        | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pd2        | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pnc        | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pd         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY     | 8       | manobo_central.p.products_id,const |      1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | jc         | NULL       | ref    | products_id         | products_id | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |      4 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>         | <auto_key0> | 4       | manobo_central.p.products_id       |     10 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  3 | DERIVED     | shp        | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,products_id | PRIMARY     | 8       | NULL                               | 208226 |   100.00 | Using index; Using filesort                  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I have options in mind.

1. I will drop subquery and use VIEWS to output the data just like using query. Because i have subquery in FROM, so i will use VIEWS from VIEWS. But some said it will affected in performances. How you guys think about this?
2. I will still using subquery, but will try and search how to optimize the query. For this one, i wanted to ask you guys, for the first result row in EXPLAIN TABLE, It shows table production p which the type 'all', how to avoid 'all' ? I've managed to use type 'eq_ref' for others table, but still have no clue why the product table is 'all'?

Again, 
Do you think i need to switch to VIEW? Or just try to optimise again the subquery.

Many Thanks!

EDIT: table products index

```
create index family_id on products (family_id);
create index idx_products_date_added on products (products_date_added);
create index material_expenses on products (material_expenses);
create index products_brand_id on products (products_brand_id);
create index products_ean on products (products_ean);
create index products_status on products (products_status);
create index tb_status on products (tb_status);
```

EDIT: table style_has_products

```
CREATE TABLE `styles_has_products` (
  `styles_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`styles_id`,`products_id`),
  KEY `products_id` (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the products table?

Comment: @Shadow I've added products index. Please see main post. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please also post the tables' unique keys? I am asking in order to know, if there can be multiple `products_description2` per `product_id`, multiple `products_local` per `product_id` and so on. I suppose it's `products_id` + `language` for `products_description`, so we get exactly one description for a product with the query, yes? But what about the other tables?

Comment: Views don't influence performance by the way. They are just for convience, so you don't have to type the same thing again and again. (Well that's not completely true; views *can* influence performance, but only in a negative way. They will never be faster, but sometimes slower, e.g. when they are nested or aggregating, so the optimizer gets problems applying criteria early.)

Comment: Some formatting would be nice

Answer (score 1):

first and foremost never write such a complex query for real time use. i'll suggest do batch process and maintain data warehouse. and use real time query on data warehouse.

still there are many things you should not do to SQL query on real time use to get performance. like never use more join operation, never put more if else conditions , never apply group by especially if table is huge, look for proper index , partition structure in table.

Comment: I disagree. I don't consider this query complex. And well, why not use SQL to aggregate data per groups? This is one of SQL's strengths. Often there are many tables involved in a query. Again: why not join the tables? Relational databases are just about this, related tables that you join in order to select their data.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is your `subquery_styles`. You don't use its result other than to filter. Criteria, however, belongs in the `WHERE` clause in my opinion. As it seems you want to exclude products for which exists a `style_id` 1967, I'd use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`:

```
WHERE p.active_status = 1
AND p.categories_top_id = 1
AND p.products_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT products_id
  FROM styles_has_products
  WHERE styles_id = 1967
)
```

The second thing is that there is no appropriate index for your query. You are selecting products with active_status 1 and categories_top_id 1, but there is no index on these columns. With the third condition on product_id not matching style_id 1967, I'd suggest one of the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on products (active_status, categories_top_id, products_id);
create index idx2 on products (categories_top_id, active_status, products_id);
```

Create both, see which is being used, and drop the other.

A last point that can and maybe should be optimized/changed is your aggregation. But in order to help here, I must know the table's unique keys. As soon as you post them, I'll extend this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Thorsten suggests, instead of `NOT IN ( SELECT )`, use

```
NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM styles_has_products
       WHERE products_id = p.products_id
         AND styles_id = 1967 )
```

`styles_has_products` needs `INDEX(products_id, styles_id)` in either order.

Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE styles_has_products`.  If it is a many:many mapping table, then see the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

Indexes need to be on the table you are going *into*, not coming *from*.  So the list of indexes for `products` probably won't be used.  This composite index *may* be useful:

```
INDEX(categories_top_id, active_status) -- in either order
```

`VIEWs` are just syntactic sugar; they do not inherently provide any performance benefit.  In some situations they hurt performance.

`pd`, `pd2`, `pls`, and some others, are not used; remove their `JOINs`.

The `SUMs` and `AVGs` will probably be incorrect.  This is because of the "explode-implode" happening with `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.  Cleanup some of the other stuff, then we can discuss how to rearrange things so the the `SUMs` and `AVGs` are done with only one row per `product_id`.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your help and tips.
I've updated in the description above for table style_has_products.
Will try to understand first your post, and will follow up your answers.
Thanks again.

Comment: You should move from MyISAM to InnoDB.